# Copy Rename Table in SQL Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to copy and rename a table in SQL EXPRESS in an mdf database. Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to copy the table?

Answer (score 5):

Try a

```
select * into [newtablename] from [oldtablename]
```

which will make a copy of your old table with a new name.

Comment: That will copy column definitions, but won't include any constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename a table using [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx). Note the warning (which will also appear when you run the stored proc):

> Changing any part of an object name can break scripts and stored procedures.